# how to denormalize ranges and store them in a data warehouse?

Tags: sql, data-warehouse

My custom web servers report session information in the form of a wall clock timestamp (start of session) and the number of wall click seconds the session lasted.

I want to store this information in a data warehouse (MySQL + start schema) in a way that will allow me to for example query the number of sessions for a particular entity at a specific time.  A requirement is that we must be able to extract time series data that will be feed to a graph.

Is there any other way to store the data than to insert a row for every absolute second of the session?

Comment: What is wrong with storing a row for every session, with a column for the entity id, a column for "start of session" and a column for "the number of wall cl[o]ck seconds the session lasted" (or perhaps easier to query: end of session)? You can convert the data to another form when you query for it.

Comment: @Mark: Because I can't really figure out how to aggregate such records and to be able to generate time series data from that.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the simplest way is to store one row per session with StartTime, EndTime in the fact table.

Let's say we have `factSession` with:

```
  ( 
   ...
  ,SessionID int
  ,StartTime datetime
  ,EndTime datetime
  ,EntityID int
   ...
  ) ;
```

and

```
TimeSeries TABLE ( TimePoint datetime ) ;
```

You can:

```
SELECT  t.TimePoint
       ,f.EntityID
       ,COUNT(f.SessionID) AS cnt
FROM    TimeSeries AS t
        LEFT JOIN factSessions AS f ON ( f.StartTime <= t.TimePoint
                                          AND t.TimePoint <= f.EndTime
                                        )
GROUP BY t.TimePoint ,f.EntityID
ORDER BY t.TimePoint
```

Comment: Works like charm. Did a test with a timeseries table with ~700 rows and a fact table with ~350,000 rows.  Quires take aprox ~45 seconds, even if I try to limit the number of rows in the session table.  Is there a way to optimize this somehow? I added an index to the start and stop times, but without gaining anything.  Here's an explanation of the query; http://pastebin.ca/1735275